# Shimano Ultegra shifters 8020 bottom plastic cover screw. Where to get it?

Tags: repair, shifter

Does anyone know the specs of the screw of part #7? Or where to get it in US?

It unscrewed and got lost. I think I might find something similar not bike-specific.

[image: Ultegra 8020 shifter parts]

Comment: Did you try your LBS?  They may just have some lying about but should be able to order from Shimano for you.

Comment: That's my next step. Thought the same, often when I ask them about such small random things they just give it for free

Comment: Different shifter, but I simply wrapped electrical tape around mine to keep the cover in place.

Comment: @Michael that's brilliant, why I didn't think about that. Can use it as a "temporary solution"

Comment: Googling the part number Y0C598020 (the cover and screw) reveals at least a few websites in the UK and Germany that sell it for under €5. My search settings don't let me see if there's anything similar in the US.

Answer (score 3):

Your local bike shop should have access to either

1. Shimano spares to order the right part.  Expect it to be expensive.
2. A "gack box" of assorted small parts left over from previous jobs - something in there might fit.

Or your final option is to take the one out of the other shifter, and measure it.  You need the width, length of thread, head shape and dimensions, tool interface, and thread pitch.  With that you should be able to find the right thing at a specialist fastener supplier, or maybe at a hardware shop (unlikely)

You may need to buy ten or a hundred at a specialist, but hey, that's spares, and may still be cheaper than a one-off via Shimano spares.

Comment: That’s what I did. Measured the screw from the other handle. It’s an M3x8. Headcap is a bit weird. It seems to be a socket with a Phillips, as I see sockets caps are usually hex.

Comment: @Art great work.  The tool interface is probably the least important feature, as long as you have the tool for it.   I have hex bolts on my cleats, and one philips-head.

Answer (score 0):

I found Shimano doesn't have spare parts for the shifters, at least not that I or my LBS has.  They usually have broken or spares that they take parts from.  One of my BIGGEST gripes with shimano.  Campy you can do a total overhaul on their shifters with pretty much all new parts.  Typically the springs are the issue though.  Not easy to do but possible.  With shimano, just replace or get it replaced through warranty.

Answer (score 0):

go to the bike shop you should be able to find a similar size screw.